# Specify data-cy value to mui textInput helper

Tags: testing, material-ui, cypress, react-props, react-tsx

I am trying to set the cypress "data-cy" to an helper text for a mui TextField.
I was able to change the style of this helper text by passing a style property to FormHelperTextProps :

```
FormHelperTextProps={{
                  style: {
                    myStyle
                  },
                }}
```

But I don't know how to specify a custom prop such as data-cy, I tried to simply add it after style property but does not have a "data-cy" property. Using the classes property to set it has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You could use `inputProps` and then pass your `data-cy` value

```
<TextField
  // ..
  inputProps={{ "data-cy": "input-xyz" }}
/>
```

Select in your cypress test

```
cy.get("[data-cy=input-xyz]").type("foo bar");
```